# What would be the default value of CheckBox and RadioButton controls ? will it be null or boolean or string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to know about the default values of checkbox and radiobutton. will it be null or boolean or string? I could not able to find the exact solution. Can you help me to figure out this....

Comment: Did you try it yourself ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. In your question you show no effort at all and it will be voted down and closed

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: it would be nice if you people help us to improve our knowledge through answers and tips to improve our questioning skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could say that the default value will be false (if we are talking about html), but depends what you are trying to do! You can take a look in a situation which the checkbox and radiobox have a purpose to be checked or not then you can take a look in the defaults properties of those tags.

About [Radiobox input](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_defaultchecked.asp) and [Checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp) you can check some nice examples on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/), there you can find some properties and examples.